# Adding multiple tuples to a list

Tags: python

I want to add all co-ordinates of line as shown below

```
coordinates = []    
for line in lines:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            coordinates.extend((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
```

To retrieve x and y co-ordinates later for further calculation

```
x,y = zip(*coordinates)
```

I get error TypeError: extend() takes exactly one argument (2 given). How can I achieve above without calling extend twice

```
coordinates.extend((x1,y1))  
coordinates.extend((x2,y2))
```

Comment: `coardinates.extend([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)])`? Also, it's `coordinates`, unless you meant something else.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That will produce a list of lists, he wants just a list

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I believe you can make the listcomp work with `itertools.chain`, see my answer

Comment: no problem. We're all here to discuss about python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements should be in a tuple or list

```
coordinates.extend(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))
```

Also the behaviour achieved by

```
coordinates.extend((x1, y1))
coordinates.extend((x2, y2))
```

can be achieved with

```
coordinates.extend((x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

Answer (score 2):

`coardinates.extend([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)])`

Or you can put the whole thing in a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain
coardinates = list(chain.from_iterable(((x1,y1), (x2,y2))) for line in lines for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line)
```

Comment: you can even use a 3rd `for` loop to avoid using `itertools` & force to `list`

Comment: Ah right, like `[coord for line in lines for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line for ((x1,y1), (x2,y2))]` ?

Comment: `[coord for line in lines for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line for coord in ((x1,y1), (x2,y2))]`

Answer (score 2):

Use list inside extend as `extend` iterate over list and append all elements in it.

`coordinates.extend([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])`

> co =[]
>
> co.extend([(1,2), (3,4)])
>
> co
>
> [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the entire process into one comprehension:

```
coordinates =  [pair for line in lines for pair in (line[:2], line[2:])]
```

Or if the lines aren't tuples themselves:

```
coordinates =  [p for l in lines for p in map(tuple, (l[:2], l[2:]))]
```